# How to replace a DB with HTML and JavaScript/JQuery to create Dynamic dependent Dropdown Select lists?

Tags: html, css, javascript, jquery, xml

Happy New Year everyone

First things first: I am not a web programmer. I know some HTML, I can cut and paste some Javascript examples to get basic things working but that is where it stops. I neither know nor do I have my boss' support nor the time to get anything PHP-oriented with a database off the ground so I'm stuck with static HTML and Javascript... I am not having fun.

I have 4 selection boxes on a web page of which the selected values make up the name of an html page on the server to retrieve. I have a date, a region, a family and a name. For every date the content basically varies. As mentioned I have no access to a database to help driving this and there is vastly too much data to hold the permutations in Arrays inside Javascript.

What I was hoping I could do, is to create files with html inside to provide the content of the boxes, like unpacking the database to files. Then when I choose a date, this date is used as a variable to become a part of a filename:

selected date: 120101

...loads the selection boxes from files...

```
> region_120101.txt/xml/js/whatever: 
A
B
C

> family_A_120101.txt
X
Y
Z

> family_name_A_120101.txt
Name1
Name2
```

If the first of each selection box is selected and all selection boxes have a value, display A_X_Name1_120101.html. If that combination has no file a message would be helpful.

If it turns out that region A has no files on disk, then I would like to display a message to the user saying the region is empty. Same if Family or Name have no available content.

Anyone have an idea how to solve this? Is JavaScript's innerHTML the answer? Should this really be JQuery and how do I tackle the matter of error trapping when the file does not exist on the server?

Anything to help me get going would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Using jQuery with an AJAX call to the outside page and a `.html()` replacement of the content should pretty much do what you want. jQuery's `.ajax()` method has an easy way of catching errors, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the fun part about HTML and REST is everything is a resource, it doesn't matter if the data is dynamically generated or just a static file, it all comes down to an HTTP request.

Specifically while flat files will work, it should be easier to use JSON (http://json.org) in the files and load them with jQuery. You may have to get the MIME type set correctly on the server but that depends on the browser and how you parse the file.

Your directory structure:

```
/data/regions.json
/data/family.json
/data/familynames.json
```

The first file (/data/regions.json):

```
[
    {"value":"A", "caption":"A"},
    {"value":"B", "caption":"B"},
    {"value":"C", "caption":"C"}
]
```

Don't put a comma after the last entry for compatibility with IE.

The select:

```
<select id="regions"></select>
```

Now the code, assuming jQuery is already included in the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON('/data/regions.json', function(results) {

        var el = $('#regions');
        $(el).empty(); // or $(el).not(':first-child').remove(); if you have -- please select 
        // region -- or whatever placeholder

        $.each(results, function(r,idx) {
            $(el).append('<option value="'+r.value+'">'+r.caption+'</option>');
        });
    });
});
```

Later you could convet this to PHP or ASP.net or whatever without really changing the client side, except maybe the url.